# C++ : dereferencing NULL pointer warning

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, null

I tried to recreate strcat function as beginner,
The warning is shown on the line:

```
dest[i] = src[j];
```

```
void strCat(char* dest, const char* src) {
        size_t len = 0, destLen = 0, srcLen = 0;
        if (dest != nullptr) {  destLen = strLen(dest);}
        if (src == nullptr) { return; }
        else { srcLen = strLen(src); }

        int j = 0;
        len = destLen + srcLen +1;
        for (size_t i = destLen; i < len; ++i)
        {
            dest[i] = src[j];
            j++;
        }

    }
```

I am facing this warning in Visual Studio 2022, the code is executed succesufully and the warning is not shown in the output window or error list. But in the code window, it underlined and saying "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'dest' "

Comment: `dest[i] = src[j];` -- What happens when `dest` is `nullptr` and `src` is not `nullptr`?

Comment: *I tried to recreate strcat function as beginner* -- The actual `strcat` function doesn't do any checking whatsoever for `null` arguments.

Comment: I don’t know what code you’re referring to when you say “the code”. Please tell us what code you’re actually executing.

Comment: You don't actually need to invoke `strLen` on `src` you can terminate your copy loop and return from function as soon as src[j]

Comment: Your function should return a `char *` to be compatible.

Comment: _Side note:_ Consider implementing [strncat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncat), rather than [strcat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat). That way, you will be thinking about the possibility of buffer overrun, something that needs consideration every time you use one of these `C` functions.

Comment: Consider what happens if the passed `dest` is a null pointer.  Even if `src` is a zero length string (i.e. it points at (the first character of) an array with first character equal to zero) your code will write to `dest[0]`  which causes undefined behaviour (and if `src` is a string with 1 or more characters, your code will *also* write to `dest[1]`, ...., `dest[srcLen + 1]` - more undefined behaviour).          Since you check for `dest != nullptr` anyway (which the standard `strcat()` does not) consider returning immediately if `dest == nullptr`.

Comment: All that said, you can safely ignore the warning (or configure the compiler not to issue it) if you can guarantee (or document a constraint that the caller must follow) that `dest` is not a null pointer.   In that case, however, there is no need for your code to check for `dest != nullptr` either.   Bear in mind your code will still have undefined behaviour if passed a bad pointer (e.g. a dangling pointer) and there is no way (without invoking more undefined behaviour) to check for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't aborting early from the function if `dest` is nullptr. That's why you get a compiler warning. You'd surely crash if `strCat(nullptr, "foo")` was invoked.  Although as others have said, actual strcat may not check either pointer parameter for null.

More pro-tips:

- You don't need to invoke strLen. Especially not for `src`. You can exit the copy loop as soon as `src` points to a null char.
- strcat is expected to return `dest`

Quite simply we can do this:

```
char* strCat(char* dest, const char* src) {
        char* result = dest;

        // validate parameters
        if ((dest == nullptr) || (src == nullptr)) {
            return result;
        }

        // advance dest to the existing null char
        while (*dest != '\0') {
            dest++;
        }

        // copy loop
        while (*src != '\0') {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
            src++;
        }

        // make dest null terminated
        *dest = '\0';
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Way back when I read [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) for the first time, I remember the joy I had when I first understood `*dest++ = *src++;`. It is a little tricky to explain, however, so I salute you in not using it here. (Post-increment binds first to `dest`, but then returns the un-incremented value of `dest`, which can be dereferenced to create an lvalue, etc., etc.) @Lightning: Check it out. It is a classic `C/C++` idiom.

Comment: Not much need for overly cramped code these days. The compiler am smart and will, if you ask it, almost certainly reduce this verbose and extremely readable function to the sort of jibber-jabber you needed to write to wrangle top performance out of antique tools.